# display datatable between two primary key in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

(sorry my english is so bad)
i try to display data in datagridview like this

```
        var db = new mydataDataContext();

        var id1 = from data in db.tbl_adads
                  where data.num1 ==int.Parse( txtnum1.Text)
                  select data.id;

        int id_1 =int.Parse(id1.ToString());

        var q = from show in db.tbl_adads
                where show.id > id_1
                select show;
        dataGridView1.DataSource =q ;
```

but when i run it and use it,compiler get error from

```
int id_1 =int.Parse(id1.ToString());
```

and say

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Linq.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

how can i do my work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id1` has type of `IEnumerable<T>` (where T is type of `data.id`). When you call `ToString()` on this variable you just get type name of variable, which cannot be parsed to int.

Possibly you need just first matching result:

```
var id1 = db.tbl_adads.Where(d => d.num1 == Int32.Parse(txtnum1.Text))
                      .Select(d => d.id)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: so how can i find the id number?

Comment: .FirstOrDefault(); gets the first value of the collection which is an int.

Comment: This is exactly why people should not use var for everything. You deprive yourself of a check which could prevent bugs like this.

Comment: @David well, usually I use `var` for queries to keep code consistent (because often queries return anonymous types and I just can't use type name for query type)

Comment: @user3142031 keep in mind, that default value for reference type (like string) will be `null`. So, if there is no matching row in your table, you will get null back. Null will throw NullReferenceException trying to call `id1.ToString()`. So, you should check `if (id1 != null)` in that case

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using Parse statements in linq query, better to do it before using it in linq query

```
var db = new mydataDataContext();

int num1_ = int.Parse( txtnum1.Text)

var id1 = from data in db.tbl_adads
          where data.num1 ==num1
          select data.id;

int id_1 =int.Parse(id1.ToString());

var q = from show in db.tbl_adads
        where show.id > id_1
        select show;
dataGridView1.DataSource =q ;
```

Comment: i think the exception you are getting while parsing to int

Comment: Actually parsing does not matter in this case. Value will be parsed only once and parsed value will be passed to expression. That would be an optimization in case of Linq to Objects - parsing would occur for each item in collection in that case.